# Javascript: Script not firing for a quickview on a product landing page

Tags: javascript, php, html, e-commerce

This is in the context of an online store, and my question isn't exactly code-based, it is more theory/concept-based. I'll try to be as detailed as possible but if there's any vagueness I'll gladly specify further.

I have two examples. The first is on a product page, where when you have a main picture view, and thumbnails below it showing different views of a product. When you click on the thumbnail it swaps the picture you clicked in the thumbnail with the picture in the main view.

The second example is on the product landing page, where the smallview picture has a "quick-look" button that pops up a "quick view" showing brief details of the product, a main picture view and then thumbnails beneath that showing different views. When you click the thumbnail, the same action as above should happen. It should swap the main view picture with the thumbnail picture that you clicked, but it isn't.

The javascript that runs this is fully functional. The same one is used for both the product page and the landing page, and it works on the product page. The thumbnails swap out and everything works fine. But on the landing page, the script isn't firing.

It isn't showing an event listener on the thumbnail for the quickview in chrome's debugger, while it is showing the event on the thumbnail in the product page. I believe I may have an idea as to what's wrong.

The script is binding successfully to the thumbnails on the product page, because on the product page the thumbnails show on the page loading. They're just there. The quickview thumbnails on the landing page do NOT have the thumbnails there on page load, they only "exist" when you click on the quickview button. I'll include a little snippet of code below showing the basic structure of the elements in question.

What would be the best way to get around this? I need to bind the eventlistener to the thumbnail pictures in the quickview.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    abcd.picturezoom= Class.create({

        initialize: function () {
            ...
        },

        swap: function (event, elem) {
            ...
        },

        open: function (event) {
            ...
        },

        opensub: function (event) {
            ...
        },

        bindQuickViewPopup: function (event) {
            ...
        },

        switchModalImage: function (event) {

        }

    });

    document.observe("dom loaded", function () {
        picturezoom
    });

    <?php if($isQuickview): ?>
        ...
        });

    });
    <?php endif; ?>
    //]]>
```

Quickview and Product Page HTML:

```
        <?php foreach ($this->images() as $_image): ?>

        <a imagenum="<?php ... ?>"

        data-main-image="<?php ... img?>"

        href="<?php ... imgfile ?>"

        class="<?php ... class name ?>"

        rel=' ... '

        id="gallery-thumbnail-quickview">

        <img src="<?php ... img?>"

        width="..." height="..." alt="<?php ... ?>" /></a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How should I approach this problem? What would be a few good steps in the right direction? The coding part isn't really the issue, I'm having a lot of trouble finding where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions.

1. Instead of the thumbnail init logic executing immediately, move it into a function that is called on full product page load and on opening of the quickView layer.
2. Use a delegated event handler somewhere higher up in the chain that does exist when the script is executed.

The delegation is quick with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click.thumbnail', 'a.thumbnail_link', function(e){
    ...
});
```

You can build delegated event handling in plain JavaScript, too: [DOM Event Delegation without jQuery](https://mattandre.ws/2014/08/small-beautiful-dom-delegation/)

If the init logic requires information specific to the product and you can open several QuickView layers from a single page, as is typical, the first solution might be preferable.

Comment: Just a heads up, your link is 404'd